# Is it a tracking cookie or something else

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

First of all sorry for asking this question on SO as this does not fit the criteria for asking questions on SO. But I still ask here as I really have no idea of a better place to ask.

So, here is the question:

I recently visited an online shopping site where I browsed 6 different products of same category(jewellery). I selected the products, came to payment page, but stopped there itself. I didn't go any further and the  closed the tab in which that site was opened, and then closed  the browser full.

I reopened the browser the next day, visited some completely unrelated site(an android forum), but, to my shock, the same 6 products that I has browsed the previous day were showing right in the center of the page AdWords box.

I couldnt understand how is that possible since both the sites are on different domains.

Can anyone please explain or point to some suitable reference...

Thnx in advance...

Comment: That's how marketing tracking works, and the reason why don't allow cookies by default in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is cookies which do this.

Here is an extended answer from the Quora Q&A website: http://www.quora.com/How-do-online-ads-know-what-Ive-been-searching-for

Comment: Thnx diggersworld....exactly what I wanted to know. Markjing your answer as accepted...